# UserHandle.CURRENT_OR_SELF cannot be resolved or is not a field (Eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse

I use Eclipse to create an application for Xposed. Аn error occurs during the build process:
"CURRENT_OR_SELF cannot be resolved or is not a field"

```
import android.os.UserHandle;
...
public class BackView implements IXposedHookLoadPackage {
...
    private void sendTags() {
        Log.d(TAG, "sendTags");
        Intent ai = new Intent("com.microntek.btmusic.report");
        ai.putExtra("type", "music.albunm");
        ai.putExtra("value", album);
        ai.putExtra("class", PACKAGE_NAME);
        context.sendBroadcastAsUser(ai, UserHandle.CURRENT_OR_SELF); <-- error
    }
```

Comment: `UserHandle.CURRENT_OR_SELF` is a hidden field, so you'll have to accomplish it in another way

Comment: In the Android Studio the same code works successfully. How to do it differently in Eclipse?